# Input selection circuitry for USB/battery

Tags: mosfet, linear

I'm making a development board, and trying to sort out the input selection circuitry, where if a battery (3.7V lipo) and USB is connected at the same time, it doesn't damage the circuitry, by stopping current flowing back into the USB.

So the design I followed was taken from the Arduino schematic: https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-uno-schematic.pdf and I chose the linear regulators + op-amp based on their properties.

Just wanted to ask whether my circuit configuration is correct?
[image: circuit]

Primarily the questions I have are:

1. MOSFET Q1 is there to act as reverse polarity protection; is this okay to use?
2. MOSFET Q2 acts as an ideal diode by permitting either the op-amp to drive the regulator, or the USB, depending on whether the battery is connected. Is this correct?
3. Is the 5V regulator correct? Other configurations have a capacitor on the output, but the reference schematic for this didn't have one; is it necessary?
4. The 5V regulator output also goes into the input of the 3.3V buck converter, so it can be supplied by a stable 5V, and thus guarantee a 3.3V output; is this correct?
5. Is it okay to have my Vbat connection pin where it's at, just after Q1? And to have that connected to the input of the 5V regulator?

Comment: What is the batteryy voltage and please show the power pins of the op-amp connected to the relevant rails.

Comment: I've updated it @Andyaka. New image of the circuit.

Comment: Are you including charging? Why not?

Comment: Charging for the LiPo battery? Yes I plan to include that. Just need to find a suitable controller. Right now my concern is to do with the input selection circuitry.

Comment: Is anyone able to help out with my questions? There's gotta be people who know more about this.